# How to install python twisted old releases?

Tags: python, twisted

Is there an apt-get install for twisted package´s old releases?
If not, what should be the path for that?

Answer (score 2):

you can use pip to install an old version

just use

```
pip install twisted==x.y.z
```

with x y and z being your version numbers

Comment: Didn´t work. twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/root/build/twisted/setu

Comment: install gcc `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: I'd install also `python-dev` (looks like you are missing `Python.h` which is *the* header file for compiling native code to be used by python)